# Federating multiple profiles to Dmgr simultaneously in IBM Websphere AS (WAS)

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to federate multiple custom profiles simultaneously to the deployment manager in IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5. It fails with the following error:

```
[root@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx bin]# ./removeNode.sh -username wasadmin
-password wasadmin
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Custom074/logs/removeNode.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the Custom074 profile
ADMU2001I: Begin removal of node: ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx
ADMU0009I: Successfully connected to Deployment Manager Server:
           ip-10-yyy-yyy-yyy:8880
ADMU0041E: Another addNode or removeNode operation is currently in progress.
           Please attempt this operation later.
ADMU0211I: Error details may be seen in the file:

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Custom074/logs/removeNode.log
```

The custom profiles initiate their own federation in my script. How do I make the profiles federate simultaneously? Is there a way to poll the Deployment Manager (using SOAP or similar) to see if the deployment manager is currently carrying out any addNode / removeNode operations so that the script can wait until it's over before it tries to federate itself?

Answer (score 1):

WAS has required serial execution of addNode/removeNode since v5, starting around 2002. There is no API to test this. Best advice is to do all addNode/removeNode serially. If have a requirement to handle concurrent addNode/removeNode requests, you'll have to trap the error, pause, retry, say N times, until successful or abandon the operation. But even so, the actual addNode/removeNode operations themselves must execute one after another to be successful.